# Getting Contact ACCOUNT_NAME and ACCOUNT_TYPE as Null in motorolla device

Tags: android, android-contacts, android-contentresolver

I am trying to get account name and account type of all the contacts in the device, but for motorolla device(motorolla argon mini) i get ACCOUNT_TYPE and ACCOUNT_NAME null.

Code used -

```
uri = ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI;

projection = new String[]   {RawContacts.CONTACT_ID,RawContacts.ACCOUNT_NAME,RawContacts.ACCOUNT_TYPE,   StructuredName.GIVEN_NAME,StructuredName.FAMILY_NAME,StructuredName.MIDDLE_NAME , ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE};

if(uri!=null)
            {
                mQueryHandler.startQuery(mDbIds[i],
                        null,
                        uri,
                        projection,
                        selection,
                        null,
                        null);
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

In Raw Contact table "ACCOUNT_TYPE" and "ACCOUNT_NAME" can be null in the case of Phone contacts, not null in case of google contacts or facebook etc.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. My problem is i am getting "ACCOUNT_TYPE" and "ACCOUNT_NAME" null for only motorolla argon mini, for other devices i am getting proper value.

Comment: It depends about the OEMs. You cannot have null account type in devices like  Google pixel where default account_type is com.google.

Answer (score 0):

In native contacts app, you can have contacts coming from different source. These contacts can be Contacts from your Phone, SIM, google contacts etc.
It totally depends upon the manufacturer of the device ( like Samsung, Motorola, Google Pixel etc) for the value of `account_type` and `account_name`.
For example, in your case Motorola phone contacts have `account_type` and `account_name` as null which might not be the case for other OEMs.

If you want to know the sources of the contacts ( other than phone/SIM contacts) 
you can use below code to iterate over all accounts and get the different sources of contacts.

```
final SyncAdapterType[] syncs = ContentResolver.getSyncAdapterTypes();
for (SyncAdapterType sync : syncs) {
    Log.d(TAG, "found SyncAdapter: " + sync.accountType);
    if (ContactsContract.AUTHORITY.equals(sync.authority)) {
        Log.d(TAG, "found SyncAdapter that supports contacts: " + sync.accountType);
        // we'll now get a list of all accounts under that accountType:
        Account[] accounts = AccountManager.get(this).getAccountsByType(sync.accountType);
        for (Account account : accounts) {
           Log.d(TAG, account.type + " |  " + account.name);
        }
    }
}
```